# jpype+pdfbox class not found

Tags: java, python, pdfbox

I'm attempting to use JPype to call Apache Pdfbox from Python, and am having some difficulty actually importing the classes. It doesn't seem to be able to read them from the jar file in the class path.

```
from jpype import java, startJVM, shutdownJVM, JPackage, JClass, getDefaultJVMPath, nio
import sys, os, codecs

pdfbox_lib = "lib/pdfbox-1.6.0.jar"
classpath = '-Djava.class.path=' + pdfbox_lib + os.pathsep + '.'

startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), '-Xmx512m', classpath)

stream = java.io.FileInputStream(java.io.File("test.pdf"))

pdfparser = JPackage('org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser')
parser = JClass('org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser')
```

At this point, the script errors out with the following:

```
java.lang.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser not found
```

I'm running on Linux with Python 2.7, and I know there's nothing wrong with the JPype installation (if there were, the stream declaration would error out). I've also tried various permutations of the class path statement and the JPackage/JClass statements, and nothing seems to matter. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Three additional jars need to be added to the class path: `fontbox-x.x.x.jar`, `jempbox-x.x.x.jar`, and `commons-logging.jar`.